# Script to edit "allow air play for"

Tags: macos, applescript, airplay, airdrop

Wanting to see if anyone can help me build or find a script that can edit "Allow air play for" within Airdrop & Handoff within system settings. It’s be default set to "current user" and want to find a way to push a script via our MDM Mosyle to set it to "everyone." Really new to MacOS scripting so I'm not even sure where to start with this.

Context: The reason for wanting to do this via a script from Mosyle is because it requires admin rights and our users are just standard users.